# Compare two tables and arrange the values in a new array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have t things working with this current setup:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    $finished = \App\Progress::select('stack_id')->get();
    $unfinished = \App\Stack::select(['id as stack_id'])->get();

    foreach ($unfinished as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($finished[$key])){
            break;
        }
        if($value->stack_id == $finished[$key]->stack_id){
            unset($unfinished[$key]);
        }
    }
    return response()->json(['finished' => $finished->flatten(), 'unfinished' => $unfinished->flatten()]);
});
```

Two current values in `progresses` table and three values in `stacks` table

Progresses

```
id user_id stack_id
6   1   1
9   1   2
```

Stacks

```
id
1
2
3
```

The response:

```
{
"finished": [
{
"stack_id": 1
},
{
"stack_id": 2
}
],
"unfinished": [
{
"stack_id": 3
}
]
}
```

Can this be done in another, more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array of `finished` and `unfinished` which contain `stack_id` and then use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) method in `PHP`.